# Karate does not display a response after a POST request with status 201

Tags: json, post, request, response, karate

I am struggling with the following test, which is usually pretty easy...

```
Feature: Testing Env Create Feature

  Scenario Outline: Create works as intended

    Given url "http://localhost:10000/api/envs"
    And request {"name": <Name>,"gcpProjectName": <GcpProjectName>,"url": <Url>}
    When method POST
    Then status 201
    And match response contains {"id": #string, "name": <Name>,"gcpProjectName": <GcpProjectName>,"url": <Url>}

    Examples:
      | Name     | GcpProjectName                | Url              |
      | tests    | D-COO-ContinuousCollaboration | https://fake.com |
      | approval | Q-COO-ContinuousCollaboration | https://fake.com |
      | demo     | P-COO-ContinuousCollaboration | https://fake.com |
      | prod     | P-COO-ContinuousCollaboration | https://fake.com |
```

I am supposed to get a response summarizing my POST request that I successfully get using curl, Postman or even Swagger, but it does not appear with Karate:

```
[failed features:
src.test.features.envtest.env-create: [1.1:13] env-create.feature:9 - path: $, actual: '', expected: '{"id":"#string","name":"tests","gcpProjectName":"D-COO-ContinuousCollaboration","url":"https://fake.com"}', reason: not a sub-string
```

Anyone knows what happens ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add quotes around string substitutions:

```
And request {"name": "<Name>", "gcpProjectName": "<GcpProjectName>", "url": "<Url>" }
```

Comment: I have the same issue with your advice, @PeterThomas

One thing to note is that even when I `* print response`, nothing appears at all. On the other hand `* print responseHeaders` works fine.

Can it have something to do with the *201* status and Karate not fetching data back ? 
I wrote plenty of POST tests working just fine with a *200* status but it is the second one I write that involves a 201 status and an "invisible" response.

Comment: @Akro I'm sure you can see from the log / JUnit HTML report what has actually come back from the server. I have no other suggestions. I'm sure you have already tried a simpler example (without `Examples` etc) and seen it work before trying to complicate things. if you are still stuck - follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue